# GenuisScan folder takes up 16 GB

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-space

I have an older iMac running High Sierra. I just ran GrandPerspective on my nearly full drive to get a visual mapping of my hard drive. It showed several large areas indicating a significant amount of space being used. One of these pointed to a folder named Genius Scan and it's taking up around 16 GB. It appears to have a copy of every folder from my home directory. Does anyone know what this folder is and why it is taking up so much space?

Comment: For iOS, [Genius Scan](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/genius-scan-pdf-scanner/id377672876) takes photos of paper documents, invoices, business cards, etc, and makes them into neat PDF files you can store anywhere to your heart's content. Have you used this app on your iPhone (assuming you have one?) Exactly _where_ is the Genius Scan folder located on the hard drive?

Comment: Thanks, i think it does the same on the mac, hence my confusion on why I have a genius scan folder with 16 GB.